# Yii2 - Change headers collection

Tags: php, yii2

I want to change the default headers collection in my RESTful api. I can change the header with set() method on every response that I send, but i don't want to write

```
$response = Yii::$app->response;
$response->headers->set('X-Powered-By','My server <devel>')
$response->setStatusCode(somecode);
$response->data = somedata;

return $response;
```

This is quite cumbersome and my Controller actions grow at length, as i have to respond to every bad request and error.
I have tried to change the response component in rest/config/main.php, but I am forbidden to change headers property, as it is read-only.

- The setStatusCode() method is quite useful, as it returns the status text automatically.

Please help.

Comment: You could always set that default header in your controller's `init` method. Either that, or make a new class that extends Yii2's `Request` class and set it there (most likely in `init` as well). You'd then update your config to point to your custom class instead of using the built-in Yii2 one

Comment: Thanks M Sost! This is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to go to the trouble of extending the response class. You can do this by configuring the `response` component of the application and adding custom headers in the `beforeSend` event, e.g.:

```php
return [
    ...
    'components' => [
        ...
        'response' => [
            'on beforeSend' => function($event) {
                $event->sender->headers->add('X-Frame-Options', 'DENY');
            },
        ],
        ...
    ],
];
```

This will add the header(s) for all responses. If you want to do it per controller, you can use `\Yii::$app->response->headers->add($name, $value);` in the `afterAction()` method of the controller.

Comment: thanks. this can be very usefull. i haven't used yii2 in a while, but i am a big fan.

Answer (score 0):

As M Sost pointed me, I found the correct path, for me. I extended yii\web\Response class to include my header.

```
namespace common\components;

use yii\web\Response;

class MyResponse extends Response
{
    public $server = 'Project <devel.local>';

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $this->headers->set('X-Powered-By',$this->server);
    }
}
```

The component should be saved in the namespace with .php exension (if this is not obvious).

This way I can add my own class to the rest\config\main.php response component and set $server property value in config.

```
....
'response' => [
    'class' => 'common\components\MyResponse',
    'format' => yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
    'charset' => 'UTF-8',
    'server' => 'Project <devel.world>', // This line can be added to change
                                         // the X-Powered-By header value
    ],
],
....
```